# Edit chart in Excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to adjust the x and y axis to use value from a specific range from the same sheet where the chart is placed.
And also, each column to be a different color (with a legend present on the chart)
Here is my code so far:

```
   Dim cht As ChartObject
   Set chtChart = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=75, Width:=300, Top:=75, Height:=300).Chart
   With chtChart
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
   End With
```

EDIT: I am fine with using just chart, it doesn't have to be ChartObject. But when I use just "Chart", another sheet gets created (besides placing the chart on the desired sheet) and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that could help you :

```
Sub Graph()

Dim Gr As Chart

        Set Gr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=75, Width:=300, Top:=75, Height:=300).Chart
            With Gr
            'Définition des données sources du graphique
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5)), PlotBy:=xlRows
            'Type de graphique
            .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
            'Place
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=NewSheetName
            'Titre
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Title"
            'Data Series 1
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
            .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "MTTF"
            'Data Series 2
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "MTTR"
            'Second axis
            .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
            '.SeriesCollection(3).Delete
            '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 1
            '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer) ' pour une ligne
            '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer) ' pour une area

            'Axis parameters
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Age"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Hours"
            .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
            .Deselect
            End With

            'Legend positioning
            With ActiveChart.Legend
                .Left = 350
                .Top = 75
            End With
            'Drawing area positiong
            With ActiveChart.PlotArea
                .Width = 550
                .Height = 350
            End With



'Clean memory
Set Gr = Nothing



End Sub
```

You'll just have to adjust your data selection and names and it should be a good start

Comment: If it's enough for you plz validate answer to close subject